# Catch "CommunicationException" from Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Good Afternoon,

I'm currently making a webapp which must be accessible for users that can be both on and off the network. But authentication is required in both cases.

The problem is I don't know how to catch the following exception that is thrown by spring security when I try to authenticate off the network :

**(javax.naming.CommunicationException)**

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: companyname.com:636; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: companyname.com:636 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: com.companyname]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:191)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:80)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
```

Here's is my "GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter" adapter :

```
@Configuration
@Order( SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER )
protected static class LdapConnection extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private ActiveDirectoryUserMapper mapper;

@Override
public void init( final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter( "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))" ).userSearchBase( "DC=companyname,DC=com" ).contextSource( this.contextSource() )
            .userDetailsContextMapper( this.mapper ).ldapAuthoritiesPopulator( this.ldapAuthoritiesPopulator() ).rolePrefix( "" );
}

@Bean
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() throws Exception {
    final DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource( "ldaps://companyname.com:636" );

    contextSource.setUserDn( "UserDn@companyname" );
    contextSource.setPassword( "password" );
    contextSource.setReferral( "ignore" );
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

    return contextSource;
}

@Bean
public LdapAuthoritiesPopulator ldapAuthoritiesPopulator() throws Exception {
    final DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator populator = new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator( this.contextSource(), "OU=Groupes,DC=companyname,DC=com" );

    populator.setSearchSubtree( true );
    populator.setGroupRoleAttribute( "cn" );
    populator.setGroupSearchFilter( "member={0}" );
    populator.setIgnorePartialResultException( true );
    populator.setRolePrefix( "" );

    return populator;
}
}
```

My goal is just to implement a "fallback mode" when ldap server is not available.

Have you any idea on how to catch the exception or even prevent it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*InternalAuthenticationServiceException* extends *AuthenticationServiceException* which in turn extends *AuthenticationException*. You can create your custom class which extends *SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler* and override

```
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
```

This method is called by Spring when the authentication flow fails.

So, in your case, if *exception* is an instance of *InternalAuthenticationServiceException* you can rely on your "fallback mode". However, at that point, your login phase has already failed and the user is considered as logged out, so you have probably to re-create "by hand" a consistent "state" in which the user is correctly logged in (e.g. add to the Spring context a proper *UserDetails* instance).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot !